# Why does the Layer 3 switch drop the ping packet?

Tags: routing, switch, switching, layer2, layer3

I am trying to ping from PC2 (not PC1, there's typo in the picture) to the router's int g0/0, but the packet is dropped at the L3 switch which is along the path. I have tried setting a default static route, a default gateway, the router-on-a-stick technique and even ospf network advertising from both the L3 switch and the router.

**SWITCH0**:

```
Switch#show running-config 
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 1203 bytes
!
version 12.2
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname Switch
!
!
!
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
spanning-tree extend system-id
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 switchport access vlan 10
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/2
 switchport access vlan 20
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/3
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface FastEthernet0/4
!
interface FastEthernet0/5
!
interface FastEthernet0/6
!
interface FastEthernet0/7
!
interface FastEthernet0/8
!
interface FastEthernet0/9
!
interface FastEthernet0/10
!
interface FastEthernet0/11
!
interface FastEthernet0/12
!
interface FastEthernet0/13
!
interface FastEthernet0/14
!
interface FastEthernet0/15
!
interface FastEthernet0/16
!
interface FastEthernet0/17
!
interface FastEthernet0/18
!
interface FastEthernet0/19
!
interface FastEthernet0/20
!
interface FastEthernet0/21
!
interface FastEthernet0/22
!
interface FastEthernet0/23
!
interface FastEthernet0/24
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
!
!
!
line con 0
!
line vty 0 4
 login
line vty 5 15
 login
!
!
!
!
end
```

**SWITCH1:**

```
Switch#show running-config 
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 1124 bytes
!
version 12.2
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname Switch
!
!
!
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
spanning-tree extend system-id
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface FastEthernet0/2
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface FastEthernet0/3
!
interface FastEthernet0/4
!
interface FastEthernet0/5
!
interface FastEthernet0/6
!
interface FastEthernet0/7
!
interface FastEthernet0/8
!
interface FastEthernet0/9
!
interface FastEthernet0/10
!
interface FastEthernet0/11
!
interface FastEthernet0/12
!
interface FastEthernet0/13
!
interface FastEthernet0/14
!
interface FastEthernet0/15
!
interface FastEthernet0/16
!
interface FastEthernet0/17
!
interface FastEthernet0/18
!
interface FastEthernet0/19
!
interface FastEthernet0/20
!
interface FastEthernet0/21
!
interface FastEthernet0/22
!
interface FastEthernet0/23
!
interface FastEthernet0/24
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
!
!
!
line con 0
!
line vty 0 4
 login
line vty 5 15
 login
!
!
!
!
end
```

**MULTILAYER SWITCH0:**

```
Switch#show running-config 
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 1643 bytes
!
version 12.2(37)SE1
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname Switch
!
!
!
!
!
!
ip routing
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface FastEthernet0/2
!
interface FastEthernet0/3
!
interface FastEthernet0/4
!
interface FastEthernet0/5
!
interface FastEthernet0/6
!
interface FastEthernet0/7
!
interface FastEthernet0/8
!
interface FastEthernet0/9
!
interface FastEthernet0/10
!
interface FastEthernet0/11
!
interface FastEthernet0/12
!
interface FastEthernet0/13
!
interface FastEthernet0/14
!
interface FastEthernet0/15
!
interface FastEthernet0/16
!
interface FastEthernet0/17
!
interface FastEthernet0/18
!
interface FastEthernet0/19
!
interface FastEthernet0/20
!
interface FastEthernet0/21
!
interface FastEthernet0/22
!
interface FastEthernet0/23
!
interface FastEthernet0/24
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface Vlan10
 mac-address 0002.16d2.a901
 ip address 192.168.1.2 255.255.255.0
!
interface Vlan20
 mac-address 0002.16d2.a902
 ip address 192.168.2.2 255.255.255.0
!
interface Vlan30
 description admin
 mac-address 0002.16d2.a903
 no ip address
!
router ospf 1
 log-adjacency-changes
 network 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255 area 0
 network 192.168.2.0 0.0.0.255 area 0
!
ip default-gateway 192.168.0.1
ip classless
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.168.0.1 
!
ip flow-export version 9
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
!
line aux 0
!
line vty 0 4
 login
!
!
!
!
end
```

**ROUTER0:**

```
Router#show running-config
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 846 bytes
!
version 15.1
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname Router
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
ip cef
no ipv6 cef
!
!
!
!
license udi pid CISCO1941/K9 sn FTX1524IP37-
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 ip address 192.168.0.1 255.255.255.0
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0.10
 encapsulation dot1Q 10
 no ip address
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0.20
 encapsulation dot1Q 20
 no ip address
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 shutdown
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
router ospf 1
 log-adjacency-changes
 network 192.169.0.0 0.0.0.255 area 0
!
ip classless
!
ip flow-export version 9
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
!
line aux 0
!
line vty 0 4
 login
!
!
!
end
```

[image: L3 switch dropping ping packet]

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

You have some problems. For example, the only way for the router to know about the other networks is via OSPF, but you have no interfaces participating in OSPF because the OSPF network statement does not match any interfaces.

Also, if the layer-3 switch is routing, as you have configured, then you should not use the `default-gateway` command. That is for layer-2 switching, not layer-3 switchin.

The default route you have configured on the layer-3 switch should really be on the router, and the OSPF on the router should then have the `default-information originate` command.

The router should not have the sub-interfaces for the VLANs configured because the routing between the VLANs should happen on the layer-3 switch.

The layer-3 switch should have the interface to the router set with `no switchport` and an IP addresses for a link between the router and switch, usually a `/30` or `/31` network, so that there are only two addresses for that network.

You should really use the `description` command on the interfaces to tell what the interface is connecting to on the other end. I am simply guessing that the trunk interfaces are the connections between the switches, so that means the router connection on the layer-3 switch is in VLAN 1, which has no addressing in the layer-3 switch.

Also, you need to make sure that you actually configured the VLANs on the switches with the global `vlan <vlan number>` command. This is not the same as creating the SVIs.

I do not see where you have DHCP configured to assign addressing and gateways to the PCs.